# Inheritance in lightning aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inheritance

I've simple lightning component let say test.cmp like below. Note that I marked **extensible="true"**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" extensible="true">
    <aura:attribute name = "attInherit" type = "string" default = "This is inherited in other component" access = "public"/> 
</aura:component>
```

Now I've another lightning component lete say test2.comp , which is like this :

```
 <aura:component implements="force:appHostable" extends = "c:test" >
   <aura:set attribute = "attInherit" value = "overrideValuefromParent" />
     
    <div style="max-width: 400px;">
       <p><lightning:formattedText value="Email info@salesforce.com" /></p>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

If I add this component in some app and try to display it, it shows blank. but if I remove markup **extends= "c:test"** from this 2nd component, then it works fine( it properly shows value as Email info@salesforce.com) Why so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have body attribute which is a facet in which the components content is rendered.

Read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_cmp_attributes.htm?search_text=inheritance) link, i have pasted relevant content below

```
<aura:component  extensible="true">

 <aura:attribute name = "attInherit" type = "string" default = "This is inherited in other component" access = "public"/>   
{!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

The child's content is rendered in the body attribute of the super component. test in your case.

> **Inherited body Attribute** Every component inherits the body attribute from aura:component. The inheritance behavior of body is
> different than other attributes. It can have different values at each
> level of component extension to enable different output from each
> component in the inheritance chain. This will be clearer when we look
> at an example.
>
> Any free markup that is not enclosed in another tag is assumed to be
> part of the body. It's equivalent to wrapping that free markup inside
> <aura:set attribute="body">.
>
> The default renderer for a component iterates through its body
> attribute, renders everything, and passes the rendered data to its
> super component. The super component can output the data passed to it
> by including {!v.body} in its markup. If there is no super component,
> you've hit the root component and the data is inserted into
> document.body.

***2 observations:***

1. Use LWC over aura
2. If you want to use aura. use composition over inheritance since salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_favor_composition.htm?search_text=inheritance) very clearly states you to avoid using it.

Comment: Yes, will eventually move into LWC soon !.  I know composition is preferred but just wanted to get some basics around inheritence